# Are storyboards going to work on ios 4?

Tags: ios, storyboard

Storyboards are new features in xcode 4.2 which simplify navigation design.
I assume new apps using storyboards are going to be working just fine on iOS 5 when it ships but I haven't seen anything about storyboards compatibility with iOS 4.
It makes sense that they would work (just like ARC is supposed to be going to work - they are a compiler / IDE feature, not runtime features AFAIK) but that's just me guessing, does anyone know if it's safe to use storyboards and be able to ship for iOS 4?

thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Storyboards themselves are NDAd. But no, storyboards are absolutely not compatible with iOS4, the rely on new runtime classes which are not available there.

Comment: Would appreciate a little more detail - what runtime classes? And why? Something to do with the transitions etc?