# iOS storyboard on iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, storyboard, app-store-connect

Well, I got the new XCode and I saw it's nice new storyboard features. It's really nice and I LOVE IT. I spent about 2 or so weeks making a new app that I wanted to update. However, when submitted it through xcode, it gave me this error

```
The Bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this Application from running on devices that were supported by previous versions.
```

So I went back and set the deployment target to 4.0, but it wouldn't let me build. Soon after I realized storyboards were only compatible on iOS 5. Is there anyway I could get it working on iOS 4 by converting them to XIB's somehow?

I really don't want to just submit a new app that's iOS 5 compatible, because most people don't have iOS 5...

Thanks.

Comment: Good question... I wonder the same thing. I thought that by just setting deployment target to 4 it would solve the problem. After all it's just a compiled binary, it should run everywhere.

Comment: Hmm just tried setting deployment target to 4.0 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Dimme: Under what? the project or target? or both?

Comment: It run on the simulator but not on the phone :S

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190571/are-storyboards-going-to-work-on-ios-4), storyboards are absolutely not compatible with iOS4 as they rely on new runtime classes.

Comment: Yeah, I know that... Is there anyway to convert the storyboards to xibs or am I going to have to start from scratch?

Comment: No there is no way. That is mainly because storyboards are more than nibs. You have the transitions embedded there as well. Even if you could convert them to nibs you would still need to write the code for the transitions.