# Can I deploy iphone app to ios4 or lower that is developed in xcode 4.3 using (Storyboards)?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I have made an app using Xcode 4.3. And for that I have used storyboards. Now I want to deploy that on my iPod that has ios4. When I run the app in **Xcode 4.3** , then it is deployed in **iPhone 5.1 simulator**.

Would it work on **iOS4**. How to recognize. If not then what's the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I try to compile a project with a Storyboard and set the Deployment Target to 4.3, I get:

> Storyboards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 and prior.

So I would say no, will not work.

Comment: but still the code that is written out of story board could work on ios 4 as navigation controller etc. Am I wrong?

Comment: Not a lot of detail, but lot's of upvotes: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190571/are-storyboards-going-to-work-on-ios-4)

Answer (score 2):

Storyboards are iOS 5 or later

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIStoryboard