# Using storyboard for iOS development

Tags: ios, storyboard

Apple introduced storyboard which saves lots of coding time. It seems that it doesn't support iOS4 and below. So is it mature enough to use storyboard for development now? How are other application doing?

Answer (score 1):

Storyboards are only supported in ios5. Mainly because they support [segues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW1)

I can recommend you using storyboards just because it brings your project screens to something logically bound, so if random developer sees it he can quickly figure out everything. 
Coding layouts is time thrown to trash. Your time and time you'll support the project, and time you'll spend trying to find bugs in this code, and time of other people that would be very much demotivated when they see the code for layouts.

In storyboards you are also forced to use MVC, so u'd never create a separate view for anything but tableview cells. (like you can do in XIB)

You should be sure that you have more than 2GB of RAM to use storyboards, because they usually contain more than 5 screens and DO lag on slow computers. The monitor size is also better be big or you'd be forced to scrolling over things all the time.

Comment: I'd like to see a storyboard riding a [Segway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segway_PT)

Answer (score 0):

Yes story board is okay to use. Just set your deployment target above 4.0. If you do that you should be fine.

Comment: *above 4.0, as it isn't supported on iOS4 and below.

Comment: come on man, storyboards are absolutely [unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190571/are-storyboards-going-to-work-on-ios-4) in ios4